# How to come up with Gauss arithmetic progression solution in this sum

Tags: summation, gauss-sums

I need to solve this:
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\\$

Using this specific method: $n + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} k\ = 0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\\$

Now this has to evaluate to: $\ n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\$

I don't know how to reach that result using that method, my results don't look like this.

Comment: Are you saying you do not understand proof by induction?

Comment: No, I saying I don't know how to evaluate this sum starting with that "method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $n + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} k = 0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k$ does not take you much far, but the method is good if you consider the sums of squares instead. Set
$$
S_1(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n k,
\quad
S_2(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n k^2,
$$
and write
\begin{align}
S_2(n)+(n+1)^2
&=S_2(n+1)\\
&=0+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k^2+2k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2+2\sum_{k=0}^{n}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n}1\\
&=S_2(n)+2S_1(n)+(n+1)
\end{align}
Comparing the starting point to the final one, we get
$$
2S_1(n)=(n+1)^2-(n+1)=n(n+1)
$$

Comment: Why did you put one of the K's to the power of two?

Comment: @Rafa_Asp1 I'm computing $S_2(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}k^2$.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you changed the exponent.

Comment: @Rafa_Asp1 I added a step, perhaps it's clearer. It's a nice trick I learnt from “Discrete Mathematics” by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik.

Comment: Using K² I will ended up with the closed form for K, and using K³ I will ended up with the closed form for K²?

Comment: @Rafa_Asp1 Yes! Quite a nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Now this has to evaluate to: $\ n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\$
>
> I don't know how to reach that result using that method, my results
>   don't look like this.

Well, if you expand the left hand side you get:

$$n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{2n}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{2n+n^{2}-n}{2}=\frac{n+n^{2}}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Which is equal to the right hand side above.

**References:**
[Young Gauss and the sum of the first n positive integers](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/) further details some history about how to perform the sum.